# ws package not working in react project because of webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

so I recently wanted to install ws but webpack suddenly threw out 17 errors.

So basically I:

1. yarn added ws
2. imported ws
3. Typed in `const connection = new ws.WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:6463/?v=1");`
4. compiled with errors

Errors:

[image]

This error is for multiple packages, basically adding a fallback "crypto... did nothing. Neither did installing crypto-browserify etc.

```js
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            path: require.resolve("path-browserify")
        }
    },
    target: 'node',
    plugins: [
        new NodePolyfillPlugin()
    ]
}
```

My webpack.config.js looks like this. I've already tried some things in there.

My question is. How do I get it working?